Foreign/Independent Movie About Tragedy, Spirit & Life
So there's this movie, based in/or around Europe that I would say took place in the early 2000's. Its main character is a little girl who seems inquisitive, and somehow meets the neighbor next door. The neighbor next door is a hunter whose little boy died(?), and the little girl manages to talk to this dead boy while visiting a cement dugout or shelter. There's also some big meaning behind an animal which I believe to be a rabbit? What is this movie called?
I think close to the beginning of the movie the little girl is left with a babysitter who doesn't care about anything and invites friends over. The father of the dead boy catches the little girl and tries to tell her it's not real, and there's no such thing as communication between the living and spirits.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give?

I think close to the beginning of the movie the little girl is left with a babysitter who doesn't care about anything and invites friends over. The father of the dead boy catches the little girl and tries to tell her it's not real, and there's no such thing as communication between the living and spirits.

Feel free to add any additional details into the question.

Sounds like the British In the Dark Half from 2012. From Wikipedia:

Marie, a 15-year-old girl, lives with Kathy, her mother, and occasionally babysits for her next door neighbor, Filthy, a poacher who is widely rumored to have murdered his wife. [...] When Filthy's young son, Sean, spontaneously dies of apparently natural causes while Marie is babysitting him, Marie becomes obsessed with her neighbor and begins to think that his stories about spirits in the hills may be true.

Rabbits were definitely involved, mostly dead ones. :( Here's the trailer:


 

You're awesome, thank you so much.
